# Source buffer being hidden when breakpoint set in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb

I have a script that is a wrapper for gdb, which just sets some environment variables and then runs gdb.  If I try to use this script to debug a program in emacs, whenever I set a breakpoint with `C-SPC`, that line to the end of the file disappears from view.

The script is

```
#/bin/sh
source env.sh
export VARIABLE_FOR_PROGRAM=false
gdb "$@"
```

`env.sh` is several lines that add directories to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

GDB is started by `(gdb  (concat "gdb.sh --annotate=3 --cd=" dir " --args " exe-dir "/path/to/my.exe " file))))`  `file` is a command line argument passed to the program I am running.

If I instead start GDB with `M-x gdb` and accept the default command (`gdb --annotate=3 my.exe`), then setting breakpoints works correctly.

`describe-text-properties` at that location gives this output:

```
Text content at position 47591:


There are 2 overlays here:
 From 47196 to 48046
  semantic             [Show]
 From 47272 to 48046
  face                 nil
  isearch-open-invisible semantic-tag-folding-show-block
  semantic-decoration  t
  semantic-link-hook   nil
  semantic-secondary   t
  semantic-tag-folding t
  semantic-tag-folding-comment-overlay nil
  semantic-tag-folding-marker-string [Show]
  semantic-tag-folding-tag [Show]


There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

`(point-max)` is 64141, so it seems like the overlays shouldn't cover the rest of the buffer.

I have a long, complicated .emacs script, and I have not figured out the minimal setup script to reproduce the problem.  Given the properties above (and that isearch-open-invisible has a value reference semantic), I suspect the problem also involves CEDET/Semantic.

Is there a known interaction between CEDET and gdb?

Is there a known problem running gdb through a script instead of directly?

I seem to recall that I created the script because running GDB with the command line of `source env.sh; export VAR=false; gdb ...` did not work.

I am using emacs 23.4.1, g++ 4.5.3 and GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-32.el5)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have enabled `semantic-tag-folding' mode, which is from the bzr version of CEDET in the 'contrib' area.  The stuff in 'contrib' is not a part of the core testing of CEDET, so I cannot speak with confidence on it's behaviors.

As a first guess, it might be good to disable whatever part of your configuration related to semantic-tag-folding mode first to see if it helps, and if not, all of the contrib loading, which needs to be done explicitly in your .emacs file.